# Jquery function being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-view-controller

I have this jQuery function that is for some reason being called multiple times when it is hit.

Basically it is a bootstrap switch above the charts to switch toggle between the chart being in `$` or in `%`. It hits multiple times.
Not always either. Seems to be when I change AJAX tabs on my page and switch another chart it happens.

Here is one of my partials

```html
@model Client_Portal.Models.HomePageViewModel
@using MoreLinq;
@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div class="m-b-20" data-ajax="true" data-url="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_CompositionTable), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(), new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"></div>

<div class="m-b-20" data-ajax="true" data-url="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Funding_Status_Table), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(), new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"></div>

@if (Model.Charts.Where(x => x.Chart.TCPD_ChartID == 1).FirstOrDefault().VisibleOnTCP == true)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block card-header height-px-55">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        Top 5 Drivers (Based on NAV) <span class="pull-right">
                            <input class="form-check-input chartSwitch" id="topDriversSwitch" type="checkbox" checked data-on-text="@Model.Currency.CurrencySymbol" data-off-text="%" />
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block chartToggle chart" id="top5" data-chart-enabled="true" data-charttoggle-opt-1="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_TopDriversChart), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"
                     data-charttoggle-opt-2="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_TopDriversChart_Percent), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })" id="top5Switch" checked data-on-text="@Model.Currency.CurrencySymbol" data-off-text="%">
                    @*<div id="top5Div" class="chartToggle"></div>*@
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@if (Model.Charts.Where(x => x.Chart.TCPD_ChartID == 2).FirstOrDefault().VisibleOnTCP == true)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 m-t-20 m-b-20">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block card-header height-px-55">
                    <h4 class="card-title" id="portfolioGrowthTitle">
                        Portfolio Growth <span class="pull-right">
                            <input class="form-check-input chartSwitch" type="checkbox" id="portfolioGrowthSwitch" checked data-on-text="@Model.Currency.CurrencySymbol" data-off-text="%" />
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block chartToggle chart" id="PortfolioGrowth" data-charttoggle-opt-1="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_CommittmentChart), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })" data-chart-enabled="true"
                     data-charttoggle-opt-2="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_CommittmentChart_Percent), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })">

                    @*<div data-ajax="true" class="chart" data-url="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_CommittmentChart), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"></div>*@
                </div>
                @*<div class="card-block" id="PortfolioGrowthPercent">
                         <div data-ajax="true" class="chart" data-url="@Url.Action(nameof(HomePageController.Portfolio_Performance_CommittmentChart_Percent), nameof(HomePageController).GetControllerName(),  new { clientPortalDataSetID = Model.SelectedDataSetID, currencyID = Model.SelectedCurrencyID })"></div>
                    </div>*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>

    Functions.Charts.CreateChart();
    Functions.Charts.SwitchChart();


</script>
```

it works when the chartSwitch input is toggled.

Below is the jquery function I am trying to have only hit one time.

```js
SwitchChart() {
    $('.chartSwitch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var divtochange = $(this).closest('.card-block').next('.card-block.chartToggle');
        Functions.Elements.ShowLoadingGIF(divtochange, $(this).attr('data-loadingmessage'));
        var opt1 = $(divtochange).attr('data-charttoggle-opt-1');
        var opt2 = $(divtochange).attr('data-charttoggle-opt-2');
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: opt1,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                complete: function (data) {


                    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var chartData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                    var response = chartData.responseJSON;
                    $(divtochange).empty();
                    $(divtochange).html(response);
                    var chartID = $(response).attr('id');

                    var functionName = 'createChart' + chartID;
                    if (typeof window[functionName] === 'function') {
                        window[functionName]();
                    }


                },
                error: Functions.Elements.ajaxError
            });
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: opt2,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                complete: function (data) {


                    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var chartData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                    var response = chartData.responseJSON;
                    $(divtochange).empty();
                    $(divtochange).html(response);
                    var chartID = $(response).attr('id');

                    var functionName = 'createChart' + chartID;
                    if (typeof window[functionName] === 'function') {
                        window[functionName]();
                    }


                },
                error: Functions.Elements.ajaxError
            });
        }
    });
```

It is inside a `functions.js` file. I've attempted moving them to the `layout.cshtml` page and they do not seem to hit at all.
I was thinking because I have to have `Functions.Charts.SwitchChart();` on every single partial that was the issue but I cannot seem to figure out where I could place it for it still to work correctly.

Really anything to point me in the right direction for why this is being hit so many times would be fantastic.

Comment: "I was thinking because I have to have Functions.Charts.SwitchChart(); on every single partial that was the issue" << yes it is. Because every time you assign another listener to all existing matching elements too. Given that you use a `<script>` immediately after the relevant elements, you could instead just attach the listener to the last matching element instead of all.